# Has and Belongs to Many Don't Delete or Nullify Join Table Entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to not delete/destroy a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association when the record is deleted? I've tried setting `dependent:` to `false`, `nil`, or random values (all still cause the delete statement to be executed)  For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

user.destroy
# DELETE FROM "tags_users" WHERE "tags_users"."user_id" = ... (don't want this)
# DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ... (do want this)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to some irritating behaviour in the internals of Rails it appears to be difficult to disable cascading deletes for has and belongs to many associations (see https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb#L1811-L1819). This isn’t the case with `has_many` - `through` so switching to that removes the `DELETE` query (under the hood they are equivalent).

```
class TagUser
  self.table_name = "tags_users"
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_many :tag_users
  has_many :tags, through: :tag_users
end

user.destroy
# DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The association of a habtm is stored in a join table, keeping those entries would make any sense at all (execpt for some statistics of course), thus rails will always delete them.

Personally I use paranoia in all my models, that should keep your `tags_users` around for longer, is `acts_as_paranoid` an option for you?

Comment: Only thing besides changing the habtm to some other type of relation might be an extension: `has_and_belongs_to_many :tags do; def destroy puts "nah"; end` (I only have mongodb apps at hands so I haven't tested it)